# Why does Xcode 5 assistant editor defaults to .m file

Tags: xcode, workflow, ibaction, iboutlet, xcode5

I realized that when launching assistance editor while working on a XIB file no longer opens the header file by default, instead it shows the implementation file. Is there a new workflow going on I am not aware of? While in the implementation file I can only seem to be able to add `IBActions`. What is the "new" way to create `IBOutlets`? Switching to header file each time??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 2 Cents:

When you create a new class using the Xcode templates, it usually provides a class extension in the implementation file for private properties. It makes a lot of sense to actually link the `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` there, because in most cases they are only ever used within the class itself.

The only exception to this that crosses my mind right now is `UIView` subclasses, and especially `UITableViewCell`. A lot of developers access the `IBOutlets` directly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

**Apple engineers' message:**
Encapsulate your `IBOutlets` & `IBActions` whenever possible!

Comment: I agree with you on Apple's intention, but it's bad practice to do this for everything if you want to unit test your code.